# Метод trim() понимает под пробельными символами тоже самое что и \s в RegExp? Или нет?

Tags: javascript

`\s` это:

> [
>   \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

`trim` это:

> whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator
>   characters (LF, CR, etc.).

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Как их сопоставить чтобы проверить?

Comment: Сделайте trim вашей верхней строке (лучше по-символьно), и увидите какие символы принимает trim. А поповоду достоверности источника - можно написать им что б уточнили.

Comment: [href1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387088/trim-in-javascript-what-this-code-is-doing), [href2](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/trim.htm), [href3](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-whitespace-from-string/), хотя проверка руками - лучший вариант (как по-мне)

Answer (score 0):

```
var whitespace      = [
    {s : '\u0009', t : 'HORIZONTAL TAB'},
    {s : '\u000A', t : 'LINE FEED OR NEW LINE'},
    {s : '\u000B', t : 'VERTICAL TAB'},
    {s : '\u000C', t : 'FORMFEED'},
    {s : '\u000D', t : 'CARRIAGE RETURN'},
    {s : '\u0020', t : 'SPACE'},
    {s : '\u00A0', t : 'NO-BREAK SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2000', t : 'EN QUAD'},
    {s : '\u2001', t : 'EM QUAD'},
    {s : '\u2002', t : 'EN SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2003', t : 'EM SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2004', t : 'THREE-PER-EM SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2005', t : 'FOUR-PER-EM SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2006', t : 'SIX-PER-EM SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2007', t : 'FIGURE SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2008', t : 'PUNCTUATION SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2009', t : 'THIN SPACE'},
    {s : '\u200A', t : 'HAIR SPACE'},
    {s : '\u3000', t : 'IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE'},
    {s : '\u2028', t : 'LINE SEPARATOR'},
    {s : '\u2029', t : 'PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR'},
    {s : '\u200B', t : 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE (category Cf)'}
];
```

[Источник](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/145439/)

**UP:**

Почему бы просто не взять, как в комментариях посоветовал @nick_n_a, `trim` каждого символа и не посмотреть?

```js
 const chars = '\f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​​\u202f\u205f​\u3000'.split('').map((char,index) => {return {char,index}});
 console.dir(chars.filter(char => char.char.trim() !== ''))
```

Comment: как ответ связан с вопросом? как приведенные символы относятся к trim функции и `\s`

Comment: @Grundy Приведенные символы - то, чем тестируют trim в v8

Comment: Стоит добавить больше информации в ответ. Так каков ответ на вопрос: _Метод trim() понимает под пробельными символами тоже самое что и \s в RegExp?_. В принципе _то, чем тестируют trim в v8_ не особо относится к заданному вопросу.